# Get internal docker PID by system PID

Tags: linux, docker, pid

After I use [exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/ExecStart) command inside docker container I can get the PID with [exec inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/ExecInspect). The problem is that this ID is not local to the container but a system PID. So I would get something like `22620` while the PID inside docker container is `695`.

I know that docker uses process namespaces to isolate its processes. So I have tried to get the internal PID with
`cat /proc/22620/status | grep NSpid`
. This indeed gave me the PID I was looking for:

> `NSpid:    22620   695`

But I need to parse this string to get the PID.
Is there a proper way to get the PID used by the docker container?

PS.

I need this process ID to kill the process started by other exec call. I cannot kill the system process as it is owned by root and I cannot use sudo.

Comment: By `Is there a proper way to get the PID used by the docker container?` what exactly do you mean? Docker command?

Comment: @k.wahome I mane without necessity to parse a string. Preferably using docker API

Comment: Why not kill it inside the container? `docker exec sh -c 'kill $(pgrep NSpid)'` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk that is exactly what I need the NSpid for.

Answer (score 0):

Och. Use `cut` to filter a section from a line.

```
grep NSpid /proc/24918/status | cut -f3
```

Will give `695` from the example.

Comment: The question was more about any official docker-style. Or dedicated system command for that as opposed to parsing the string.